# Issue tracker with visual dependency graph

Tags: issue-tracker

I need an issue tracker like RT, or GitHib issues that visually shows dependencies, and especially blockers.

I want this so I can have a heads up display of when issues are blocking other issues - hard with a simple list.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a project management site I built with [TRAC](https://trac.edgewall.org/) that had this capability. [Here](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketDepgraphPlugin) is one plugin that does this.

Comment: As an impartial observer, I say that this answers the question. @xconspirisist where are you?  Now, if only there was something similar for Jira

Comment: I just stumbled across https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kitologic.pathfinder/cloud/overview    which seems eminently affordable at US $50/month for 2,000 users.

Comment: Alternatively, https://github.com/pawelrychlik/jira-dependency-graph  is open source tool